# How to get rid of excessive top margin in the first element of a printed page

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML code with minimum style for printing:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media print {
  @page {
    margin: 20mm 20mm;
  }
  h1 {
    margin-top: 20mm;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer</p>
  <p>asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer</p>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer</p>
  <p>asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I print the page it looks like this (without the green/red annotations, of course):

[image]

Note how the first title has a big top margin: first the page margin then its own top margin.

The real document is much longer and I would like to automatically:

- Keep the margin above all headers when there is text or other content above
- Remove the margin above all headers when they are the first element of the printed page, since there is already a page margin

How can I do that?

Comment: How about creating your own class in CSS and then use that?

Comment: `h1:first-of-type{margin-top:0;}` will do too.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That's good to know too, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target all `h1`'s that are *not* the first child, so simply add this to your `h1` style `h1:not(:first-child)`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @media print {
        @page {
          margin: 20mm 20mm;
        }

        h1:not(:first-child) {
          margin-top: 20mm;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer</p>
    <p>asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer</p>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer</p>
    <p>asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer asdf qwer</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! ^^ Can't accept this soon it seems, but I will in a couple of minutes. :-)

Comment: What if each `h1+p+p` is contained within a `<section>`? (it seems I simplified too much the reproducible case...) :-D

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice your comments - with that use case then you could just convert the CSS to target the `section` like this: `section:not(:first-child) { ... }` instead of the `h1`

Answer (score 1):

Write css in the h1 tags:

```
h1{
    margin:0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to SO! ^^ Unfortunately, that would require manual annotation of each tag and the real document is much longer, so that would not be feasible. :-)

Comment: Thanks. You can also apply css to all of them with an `*` sign or you can also give a class to each label. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin to a negative number, works for me!